# image source not readable при загрузке изображений

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь загрузить картинку с помощью пакета intervention/image, в ответ же получаю оишбку Image source not readable. Почему она вовзникает и как вылечить?

Контроллер:

```php
    public function upload(){
        if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image = Image::make($request->file('image'));

            $image->save(public_path('/storage/uploads/' . time() . '.jpeg');

        }
    }
```

маршрут

```php
    Route::post('/products/{id}/upload', 'Controller@upload')
        ->name('image.upload);
```

Форма

```php
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'image.upload', 'files' => 'true']) !!}
    {{ Form::file('image', [
        'class' => 'form-control-file'
      ])
    }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157824/intervention-image-upload-error-image-source-not-readable) Думаю вам поможет

Comment: Добавте для ясности в вопрос форму и маршрут.

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy , добавил

Comment: HTML хелперы? что за версия laravel ?

Comment: $image->save(public_path('/storage/uploads/)); Ошибки: 1) метод save дожен содеражть путь и имя сохраняемого файла  save(public_path('/img/'.image_xxxx.jpg)) , где вместо  image_xxxx.jpg обычно идет сгенерированная переменная с именем и расширением. 2) Вы указываете путь как storage/uploads - это обычно символьная ссылка на папку в корне сайта - она у вас создана?

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, 2 - Да, создана. 1 - Спасибо.

Comment: @HELP, что с проблемой то ? )

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy , увы, обрадовался я слишком рано, ибо с проблемой ничего не произошло. Код контроллера обновил.

Comment: @HELP, а если сменить папку с корневой на какую нибудь нейтральную и существующую? Пример /assets/images/  ?

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, забыл упомянуть, версия лары 6.6.0.
Совет не помог, резуьтат - ничего.